# How to make RethinkDB to call a java function whenever new insertion happens?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rethinkdb

**Hello all,**
I am new to **Rethink-db** can anyone help me with this as i mentioned in above query.
I am creating one **java service** with **Rethink-db** so whenever new entries inserted into Rethink-db a java method should call by **Rethink-db** itself with data that i inserted. And is this possible to achieve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you have proper dependency set, below code may help you.

```
static Connection con = r.connection().hostname("localhost").port(28015).db("db_name").connect();
public static final RethinkDB r = RethinkDB.r;
public static void getChangeEffect() {
    Result<Object> changes = r.table("table_name").changes().run(con);
    for (Object change : changes) {
        System.out.println(change);
    }

}
```

The above code will execute and prints all the rows whenever a new insertion takes place.